# Loading two versions of same JS libary

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

Currently migrating from an older version of a JS library (sweetAlerts), to a newer version.

Both versions load, but I want to be able to use the updated library, but unsure how to reference it in JavaScript to use the newer library. Any input on how to do this would be appreciated.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'sweet-alert', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/sweetalert.min.js', array(), $this->version, false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'sweet-alert-latest', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/sweetalert-latest.min.js', array(), $this->version, false );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sweetalert.js uses the global `swal` in both version 1.*.* and version 2.*.* of its library. Therefore if you load both `js/sweetalert.min.js` and `js/sweetalert-latest.min.js` the first one to define the global `swal` will be used, the second will be ignored or cause a console error.

To prevent this only load one library such as:

```php
// PHP
wp_enqueue_script( 'sweet-alert-latest', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/sweetalert-latest.min.js', array(), $this->version, false );
```

And update any references targeting old SweetAlert code according to the [migration documentation](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#upgrading-from-1x)

---

Alternatively If you want to use both libraries concurrently you could utilise ES6 modules with a compiler such as babel

```js
// Javascript
import swal as oldswal from '/my-local-js-directory/sweetalert.1.5.1.js';
import swal as newswal from '/my-local-js-directory/sweetalert.2.1.0.js';

// Old alert
oldswal({
  // Old alert config here
});

// New alert
newswal({
  // New alert config here
});
```

Ref: [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

With common JS you could do something like this

```
const oldswal = require('/my-local-js-directory/sweetalert.1.5.1.js')
const newswal = require('/my-local-js-directory/sweetalert.2.1.0.js')
```

Comment: Great answer and well explained! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not a WordPress related question but external JS library.

Anyway, if for this case you can load both JS files and loading the library twice has no conflicts, I would use the `dependency`, `version` and `in_footer` parameters for the wp_enqueue_script function as the following:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'sweet-alert', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/sweetalert.min.js', array(), '1.0', true );  
wp_enqueue_script( 'sweet-alert-latest', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/sweetalert-latest.min.js', array('sweet-alert'), '2.0', true );
```

Note that I'm not using the class version (`$this->version`).
This way you are telling WordPress to load v 1.0 first and v 2.0 later, also is a good practice for page performance to load JS on footer, unless you are already handling that in some other way.

I hope this can help.

Comment: The `$ver` argument is to aid with cache busting and isn't agnostic to the versioning of libraries included. By changing `$this->version` to `1.0` this will only clear previous caching of these files, and force them to be fetched by browsers which previously cached them due to a change in a URL query parameter. Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: @CraigPearson, you are correct, internally WordPress uses the `ver` parameter to handle cache, but looks like the version property(``$this->version`) is part of a class which may change several times over development so he is forcing to load the library again even for those already having the cached version.
The docs say `specifying script version number`  which we can map to the library version for better readability and a more accurate external library dependency handling..

Comment: apologies if this came across in the wrong way, like you I am just trying to help. I thought my comment was valid as your suggested answer only aims to clear caching and addresses versioning, which the OP didn't request

Comment: No problem @CraigPearson, your answer is more descriptive and I believe is the needed workaround. My answer is just making sure the assets queue order is correct, then we have another issue that is related to the JS library which is out of scope here.